# iOS screen break open closed principal

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I am facing one issue, I have designed one screen which contain table cell. after some time I got new screen to be designed in which 90% cell design is same as I already implemented, but this time I don't want to make any separate custom view and reuse in already implemented table cell and new cell.

So, How can I reuse table cell in new screen without modification of existing one?
Does iOS UI element break open closed principal? or I am thinking in wrong way?

Comment: Is this in a Storyboard or code?

Comment: Use .xib as tableview cells.

Comment: @flanker Storyboard

Comment: @grantespo Yes, This is one of the option. but in earlier tableview I have used prototype cell and loaded ui component there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first option is to create a custom view that has the same design and embed that in each of your table view cells and customize the rest of the part.

Second, you can pass the state/type of the cell as per your screen requirements. Based on the state/type, you can hide/unhide the required elements.

Also, views are design components. If we modularise them well enough and keeps them separate from business logic, they won't come in way of breaking SOLID principles. Apple keeps it's logical and UI components in separate frameworks. For example, `Contacts` and `ContactsUI`.

Comment: Yes, same options I was approaching before putting the questions.